# Option to fail Xilinx process if pins are unconstrained

Tags: fpga, xilinx, pinout

I am using Xilinx WebPack 13.2 and I recall there being a setting to force the Xilinx process to fail if a top level input/output net isn't constrained to a pin. I would like for the process to fail the design flow instead of automatically assigning a pin and finishing the process. Unfortunately I can't seem to find where that option is in the ISE, where is that option in the Xilinx ISE?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never found that option - much as I'd love to have it! The closest I've found is the opposite: "fail if there are things constrained which don't exist".

My (Windows CMD.exe) workaround is a post-map script which looks in the `.pad` file for the string "|UNLOCATED|".

```
@find "|UNLOCATED|" %DESIGN%.pad || goto padsok
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I've been away from the Xilinx design flow for a few years now so maybe my memory is foggier than I thought. I'll give that a shot tonight and see what else pops up in here.

Comment: In order to execute this script did you have to give up the ISE GUI? I can't seem to find how to hook into the design flow in the GUI and it seems I would have to get the commands of the design flow and put them in a batch file and run from the command line. If there is a way to hook it into the GUI flow could you point me to where you set up that script at? Thanks. (Also I did find the option you mentioned which was called allowing unmatched constraints which was listed as part of the Translate properties)

Comment: I have never used the ISE GUI to be honest, I started scripting right from the word go.  As far as I know there's no way to add custom steps to the process (which is one of the reasons I like to roll my own scripts). For help with scripting, try here: www.boldport.com (although it seems to be down ATM)

Comment: I'll check that website out later, hopefully it comes back online. I was able to verify that your method would work so I upvoted and marked as answered. Great job answering what apparently turned out to be a trick question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Bitgen and vivado both fail if the design's top level ports are unassigned (no LOC constraints).  As far as I know, your options will be limited with Project Navigator (the ISE GUI).  But if you use PlanAhead - there is many ways to stop the flow.  Basically, you can use PlanAhead as your front end, but 13.2 is quite old at this point.  The simplest approach is to write a small planAhead Tcl script to query all the input ports and if any of them have unassigned input ports.  I do not recall if report_drc reported this as a drc violation at that time, but it does now  - there is a DRC violation UCIO #1 categorized as a critical warning for all unplaced IO ports.

The tcl script can be very simple, even something like this (once the design is loaded with edif/ucf):

```
if {[llength [get_ports -filter {LOC == ""}]] > 0} {
   puts "ERROR - found ports that were not placed"
   # exit the tool or do whatever you want to 
   exit 1
}
```